# Viewing continuous linear functionals on $l^p$ spaces in component form.

Tags: functional-analysis

So this keeps coming up for me in problems concerning properties of some $l^p$ spaces. But it seems really useful to be able to represent a linear functional f on a given $l^p$ space as $(f_1, f_2, ...)$. Then $f(x)$ for $x \in l^p$ is equal to $f_1(x_1) + f_2(x_2) + \ldots$ But it was never explained in my class why this is valid. (we aren't following a textbook, so I don't know what to refer to in order to try and answer this).

Why should I believe that every linear functional on such spaces can be though of in these terms? Can you point me towards something to clear this up? I'm not even sure what to refer to this as in order to try and find some related explanations. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need $1\leq p<\infty$ as mentioned by kahen above. Let $e_i$ be the element of $l^p$ with $1$ in the $i$th coordinate and $0$ elsewhere.

If $x=(x_1, x_2, \dots)\in l^p$, then let
$$x^n = (x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n, 0, 0, \dots)$$

It's easy to see that $x^n \rightarrow x$ in $l^p$. (Note that this is utterly false if $p=\infty$, and indeed, the answer to your question is "no" in that case.)

So if $f$ is a BOUNDED linear functional on $l^p$, then
$$ f(x) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(x^n) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_1^n x_i f(e_i) = \sum_1^{\infty} x_i f(e_i) $$
which, if I understood correctly, is what you wanted.

There are some details here to fill in, but you should be able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Your $(f_1,f_2,\ldots)$ is in $\ell^q$, where $\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{p}=1$. To prove, use Holder inequality: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality

Every functional analysis book should have this.

Comment: Only for $1 \leq p < \infty$. Not for e.g. $p = \infty$.

Comment: You are right. Continuous linear functionals on $\ell^{\infty}$ are more complicated, although every element of $\ell^1$ is one of such.

Comment: @TLC perhaps I wasn't clear. Why should I believe that a given functional on this sequence can be though of as a collection of functionals acting on the respective components? That is, $f$ as $(f_1,f_2,...)$.

Comment: You need to prove that for any $(f_1,f_2,\ldots)\in \ell^q$, the functional on $\ell^p$ defined by $(x_1,x_2,\ldots)\to $f_1x_1+f_2x_2+\cdots$ is continuous. And then you have to prove the converse, i.e. every continuous linear functional is of this kind.